# What is the time complexity of my solution?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

**Scenario:**

I have a method called "searchRange" where I need to search for the min and max index where target occurs in the supplied input array.

**Question:**

I think the time complexity of this solution is O(n) because I am looping over the input just once. Is my understanding correct?

**Code:**

```
public class Solution {

    public int[] searchRange(int[] nums, int target) {
        if (nums == null) {
            return new int[2];
        }
        int min = -1, max = -1, l = nums.length;
        int[] ans = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (nums[i] == target) {
                if (min == -1) {
                    min = i;
                } else {
                    max = Math.max(i, max);
                }
            }
        }
        if (min != -1 && max == -1) {
            max = min;
        }
        ans[0] = min;
        ans[1] = max;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks, I now know that the time complexity of the above algorithm is O(n). I am trying to reach towards O(logn). I tried to use a variant of binary search to discover the min and max indices. Is the time complexity of the method given below O(logn)?

```
public int[] searchRange(int[] nums, int target) {
    if (nums == null)
        return new int[2];
    return searchRange(nums, target, 0, nums.length - 1);
}

public int[] searchRange(int[] nums, int target, int l, int h) {
    int[] ans = new int[] { -1, -1 };
    int middle = (l + h) / 2;
    if (l > h)
        return ans;
    if (nums[middle] == target) {
        if (middle < nums.length - 1 && nums[middle + 1] == target) {
            int[] right = searchRange(nums, target, middle + 1, h);
            ans[1] = right[1];
            ans[0] = middle;
        }
        if (middle >= 1 && nums[middle - 1] == target) {
            int[] left = searchRange(nums, target, l, middle - 1);
            ans[0] = left[0];
            if (ans[1] == -1) {
                ans[1] = middle;
            }
        }
        if (ans[0] == ans[1] && ans[0] == -1) {
            ans[0] = ans[1] = middle;
        }
    } else if (nums[middle] < target) {
        return searchRange(nums, target, middle + 1, h);
    } else {
        return searchRange(nums, target, l, middle - 1);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: You should consider what happens when your input consists of negative numbers less than `-1`

Comment: I don't think it's input.  It's the array index of where `target` is found.  He's recording the first and last index of the target number. `-1` is an impossible value for an array index.

Comment: Does that code work?  Have you tested it?  You have the right idea to go after a binary search to reach O(logn).

Comment: This is O(logn) assuming now that your input array is sorted, whereas your initial version didn't require that.  So, depending on how you are getting your sorted array, this should be a better solution than before, overall.  It's O(logn) because each recursive call you are dealing with half the array.

Comment: Is your array sorted? You can definite get O(logn) with binary search easily if your array is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple O(n) where n is the length of your input array.  You are going to loop through the entire array on every call to the searchRange() function.